# LoaderCursor demo chokes

Tags: android

I'm trying out the LoaderCursor example in the API Demo:

```
package com.example.android.apis.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;

/**
 * Demonstration of the use of a CursorLoader to load and display contacts
 * data in a fragment.
 */
public class LoaderCursor extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            CursorLoaderListFragment list = new CursorLoaderListFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class CursorLoaderListFragment extends ListFragment
            implements OnQueryTextListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

        // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
        String mCurFilter;

        @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Give some text to display if there is no data.  In a real
            // application this would come from a resource.
            setEmptyText("No phone numbers");

            // We have a menu item to show in action bar.
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
            mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null,
                    new String[] { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS },
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }, 0);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);

            // Start out with a progress indicator.
            setListShown(false);

            // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
            // or start a new one.
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        @Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Place an action bar item for searching.
            MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
            item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
            item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
            SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());
            sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            item.setActionView(sv);
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Update
            // the search filter, and restart the loader to do a new query
            // with this filter.
            mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
            return true;
        }

        @Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // Don't care about this.
            return true;
        }

        @Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Insert desired behavior here.
            Log.i("FragmentComplexList", "Item clicked: " + id);
        }

        // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve.
        static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS,
            Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,
            Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
        };

        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
            // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
            // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
            // currently filtering.
            Uri baseUri;
            if (mCurFilter != null) {
                baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                        Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
            } else {
                baseUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            }

            // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
            // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
            String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                    + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                    CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        }

        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
            // old cursor once we return.)
            mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

            // The list should now be shown.
            if (isResumed()) {
                setListShown(true);
            } else {
                setListShownNoAnimation(true);
            }
        }

        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
            // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
            // longer using it.
            mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The above codes try to load contacts information from "People" app. But the LoaderCursor stops while loading:

```
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=1331, uid=10043 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:358)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:310)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:56)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:42)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:255)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:55)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-16 01:07:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     ... 4 more
```

This is the first time I come across issues of Loader and I have no idea what's going wrong here. So what could be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing the android.permission.READ_CONTACTS permission in your [Android manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). You can see that the System is throwing a SecurityException.

Just open the XML file and add this line to it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Otherwise the system want grant you access to the contacts to protect the user (result of the sandbox concept).

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri
>   content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=1331, uid=10043
>   requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

You forgot to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>` in manifest.

Comment: @downvoter what was the issue in answer.Don't know why peoples behave like this :(

Comment: maybe its because Tim already answered this question and your answer seems like a copy.